# Hasura Error - GraphQL error: field "user_id" not found in type: 'projects_insert_input'

Tags: graphql, hasura

I'm trying to add a new project with a connected user assigned to a project but I continue to receive an error 'GraphQL error: field "user_id" not found in type: 'projects_insert_input''

Each project has a user_id column mandatory (I can add projects inside the graphiql editor on hasura, but not on my client)

mutation

```
const ADD_PROJECT = gql`
  mutation ($project: String!,  $isPublic: Boolean!, $user: String!) {
  insert_projects(objects: 
    {
        title: $project, 
        is_public: $isPublic,
        user_id: $user
    }
    ) {
    affected_rows
    returning {
      id
      title
      created_at
      is_completed

    }
  }
}
 `;
```

```
const ProjectInput = ({ isPublic = false }) => {
    let input;
    const [projectInput, setProjectInput] = useState('');

    const [addProject] = useMutation(ADD_PROJECT);

    return (
        <form className="formInput">
            <input
                className="input"
                placeholder="What needs to be done?"
                value={projectInput}
                onChange={e => (setProjectInput(e.target.value))}
                ref={n => (input = n)}
            />

            <button onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addProject({
                    variables:
                    {
                        project: projectInput,
                        isPublic,
                        user: "auth0|5e6d66e02ae6a80c8bc42eb4"
                        // description: projectDescInput
                    }
                });
            }}>Click me</button>
            <i className="inputMarker fa fa-angle-right" />
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: Do you have any permissions configured? Generally in Hasura console, the mutation works because you might have configured admin secret which gives full access. 

Also how is the apollo client configured? What are the headers being passed?

Comment: ^Similar questions as above. In addition, seems like you may be missing array brackets [ ] when using plural `insert_projects` as such `insert_projects(objects: [{...}]) { ... }`. Relevant documentation: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html#auto-generated-insert-mutation-schema

Answer (score 21):

It looks like a permissions error. In the section called **Data**, select the corresponding table (*project* in your case?) and open permissions tab. There, you should set *insert* permissions to the corresponding role. In case you're not using custom roles, you must modify permissions to *public* role.

The key here is that the console uses *admin* role, so you can do everything in there.

Be careful, since modifying *public* role permissions might be risky.

[image: Hasura permissions section]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the following error I finally figured out was granting permission

```
Error: field "typewallet" not found in type: 'recharge_register_bool_exp'
```

In Hasura database go to Permission and select a column you want to have insert permission

[image]